# Object not visible when rendered

Tags: rendering, visibility

An object is missing when rendered. It is not restricted, clickable, and can be seen in the 3D View. I have searched the internet, and this forum as well but found nothing.

I have provided 2 screenshots if I ever did something wrong
Please tell me when you need another screenshot of something.

[image: viewport]

[image: render]

Comment: what object are you talking about? maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5738" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5738/)

Comment: thanks but again, what object are you talking about? Everything that is supposed to visible is visible, and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Some objects in your scene do not have meshes, so they are not meant to be rendered, but only exist as objects to help you animate.

Also, there is an object called IK/FK_panel that is not rendered because it is hidden from the render. To re-enable rendering of this object, click the camera icon that appears greyed out in the object list.

Comment: The IK/FK Panel is the panel used to animate, it is not suppose to be shown in rendering